# How to detect which program will be run?

Tags: linux, shell

Your system has 2 versions of the same utility installed, both which have the same filename.

How would you find out where the utility you would run by default is located?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

If the utility's file name is "foo", type `which foo`

Comment: not always , if '.' is is the first in PATH , it will show current dir.

Comment: If '.' is first in PATH, it will show "./foo", which seems to me like it answers the original question.  The original question asked what would be run "by default," which I would take to mean by default within the current environment, because it is the current environment that defines what the default is.  Both the PATH and current working directory are part of the current environment.

Answer (score 0):

You'are looking for `which` command

```
which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.
```

Let's say you have `perl` installed in `/usr/bin/perl` and `/usr/local/bin/perl` and if the default path is the second one then

```
$ which perl
/usr/bin/local/perl
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the $PATH.

```
echo $PATH
```

The first is started default.

or

```
which
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to which , whence gives you whence command from Korn Shell tells how a name would be interpreted by the shell: it detects commands and aliases, and searches your path.

```
whence {executable-you-are-looking-for}
```

and also in linux, just typing name & hitting tab will show list of available versions with which you can run.